# Rails 4: changing model from ActiveRecord to STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to change a model type from `ActiveRecord::Base` to an STI architecture. I'm writing a loop to create everything I need like so:

```
EditedArticle.each do |e|
  c = Component.create(name: e.name, body: e.body, type: 'EditedArticle', user_id: e.user_id, state: e.state, description: e.description, cover_id: e.cover_id)
  e.publication.update_attribute(:component_id, c.id)
end
```

I need to run this loop so that `EditedArticle` changes from its own table to a subtype of `Component`. Is this loop going to work? Already the class begins like this:

```
class EditedArticle < Component
  ...
```

So potentially `EditedArticle.each` will return nothing. Do I need to keep `EditedArticle < ActiveRecord::Base` until after this loop is done? Is there a better way to do this? This seems awfully hacky.

Comment: I don't think it's hacky and besides, you're only going to run this loop once so I don't think it matters anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your articles with raw sql query like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT * FROM articles').each do |article|
  # article is basically a hash of attributes (i.e. article['title'])
end
```

Comment: It's that easy? Awesome. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have existing `EditedArticle` models in your database within the `edited_articles` table and you're trying to convert those to `Component` models with a type of `EditedArticle`.

If so, you can temporarily keep `EditedArticle < ActiveRecord::Base` until you've ran the loop and converted the existing `EditedArticle` models to `Component` models with type `EditedArticle`, at which point you can delete the existing `edited_articles` table and change the model to `EditedArticle < Component` to enable STI.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The logic here makes sense but ideally I'd rather not have to deploy to production, run a loop with a temporary codebase, and redeploy again just to get the data correct. Seems very dangerous to me, especially since my deploy time is around 15 minutes.

Comment: Why would you need to temporarily deploy? `rails c production` to start console within production database. Run the above loop to convert. Deploy STI enabled code.

Comment: Ah, of course! Don't know what I was thinking there. That totally makes sense. Thanks!